# InvalidCastException was unhandled

Tags: c#, inheritance, foreach, reference, .net

Just have a quick question... any help would be greatly appreciate!

I'm writing a database. I have a class called "Mechanism" which is inherited by two other classes called "motorcycle" and "automobile." How would i go about printing the contents of motorcycle or automobile - depending on what the user has decided to enter into the database?

this is what i have so far, it's giving me this error: InvalidCastException was unhandled. Unable to cast object of type "ConsoleApplication1.Automobile" to type "ConsoleApplication1.Motorcycle"

```
foreach (Mechanism m in mechanisms)
{
    //ptr = m;
    if (flagAuto == true)
    {
        Mechanism ptr = null;
        ptr = m;
        Console.WriteLine("ptr = " + ptr);
        Console.WriteLine("ptr2 = " + ptr2); 
        ptr2 = (Automobile)ptr;
        Console.WriteLine("inside Auto");
        ofp.WriteLine("" + (ptr2.getManufacturer()));
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr2.getModel());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr2.getModelYear());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr2.getVIN());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr2.getInitialPurchasePrice());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr2.getPurchaseDate());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr2.getSizeOfEngine());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr2.getTypeOfFuel());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr2.getNumberOfDoors());
        ptr2 = null;
        ptr = null; 
        Console.WriteLine("finishinge Auto");
    }
    else if (flagMotor == true)
    {
        Mechanism ptr = null;
        ptr = m;
        Console.WriteLine("ptr = " + ptr);
        Console.WriteLine("ptr2 = " + ptr1); 
        Console.WriteLine("inside Motor");
        ptr1 = (Motorcycle)ptr;
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr1.getManufacturer());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr1.getModel());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr1.getModelYear());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr1.getVIN());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr1.getInitialPurchasePrice());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr1.getPurchaseDate());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr1.getSizeOfEngine());
        ofp.WriteLine("" + ptr1.getTypeOfMotorcycle());
        ptr1 = null;
        ptr = null; 
        Console.WriteLine("finishing Motor");
    }
```

the flags are supposed to keep track of which type of vehicle is trying to be entered into my database - then it should write it out to a text file..

Comment: having to cast to a specific subclass is a code smell - why do you have to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means the value of the flag is wrong.

You should do this instead:

```
if (m is Automobile)
{
    Automobile autoMobile = m as Automobile;
    //.. work with autoMobile
}
else if (m is Motorcycle)
{
    Motorcycle motorCycle = m as Motorcycle;
    //.. work with motorCycle 
}
```

By the way, you're doing the same thing in the both branch. That implies, that you could implement them in a base class (`Mechanism`), call those methods on `m` object.

Comment: Woaha! thanks!! I didn't know about "is." Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Type-by-type logic should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Not all `Mechanism` can be cast to `Motorcycle`s. In your particular case, you have an instance of `Automobile` and you are trying to cast it to a `Motorcycle` (that's what the exception message says). You can't do that (A `Dog` can not be converted to `Cat` even though both are `Animal`).

Instead of doing type-by-type logic, why don't you just override `ToString` or provide a method on `Mechanism` that can be overridden by `Motorcycle` and `Automobile`. Then you can just invoke `ToString` or that method, without evening having to worry about the particular type. That's polymorphism! Here's a rudimentary example to get you started.

```
class Mechanism {
     public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetDetails() {
          // assume these are all defined by Mechanism, omitted here for brevity
          yield return this.getManufacturer();
          yield return this.getModel();
          yield return this.getModelYear();
          yield return this.getVIN();
          yield return this.getInitialPurchasePrice();
          yield return this.getPurchaseDate();
          yield return this.getSizeOfEngine();
          yield return this.getTypeOfFuel();
     }
}

class Automobile : Mechanism {
     public override IEnumerable<string> GetDetails() {
          foreach(var detail in base.GetDetails()) {
               yield return detail;
          }
          yield return this.getNumberOfDoors();
     }
}

class Motorcycle : Mechanism {
     public override IEnumerable<string> GetDetails() {
         foreach(var detail in base.GetDetails()) {
             yield return detail;
         }
         yield return this.getTypeOfMotorCycle();
     }
}
```

Then you can just say:

```
foreach(var mechanism in mechanisms) {
    foreach(var detail in mechanism.GetDetails()) {
        ofp.WriteLine(detail);
    }
}
```

Aye, it's beautiful!

Comment: @BlueButtons: Please mind my last suggestion. Do not do type-by-type logic!

Comment: @Jason: They're different flags. You incorrectly wrote it here.

Comment: @Jason: As Nawaz said I think you misread the question, the flags are flagAuto and flagMotor, they are not the same. Also even if it were the code above surely the first block will be evaluated and the second will be skipped because its in the else of the first if..The flags aren't changing though as others have commented. I'd like this answer a lot more if that were removed. ;-)

Comment: And FWIW my +1 was for the last bit which I think is the correct answer rather than type checking. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply put, your `flagMotor` is lying to you; the object is an `Automobile`, as the error message says, but you're trying to cast it to `Motorcycle`. You need to find out why your flags are set wrong.

Or you could eliminate the flags altogether, and use C#'s `is` operator:

```
if (m is Automobile) {
    // ...
} else  if (m is Motorcycle) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i don't think that it's set wrong. What seems to be going on is that my list contains types of both vehicles. Hence, when it gets into trying to print it to a file, it gets confused as to what it should be printing i'm guessing? It seems that once i set m = a vehicle type (whether it be Motorcycle or Automobile) i can't seem to re-set it to be a reference to something else... Any ideas?

Comment: Heh. Well, how do you expect the flag's value to change inside the loop? It's not going to happen by magic. Abandon the flags and use `is`, as I suggest above; that'll let you decide based on each individual object.

Comment: Type-by-type logic should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks :o) the "is" really helped! Didn't know this existed!!

Comment: @Jason is totally right, of course -- the *really* right way to do this is with polymorphism. But I honestly don't think we're ready for that here in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

As Ernest Friedman-Hill mentions, with your current archetuture, the flags are not being set correctly.

It may be worth mentioning, (not having seen the full source for your classes), it looks like perhaps your object hierarchy isn't quite standard OOP. You should probably have the Mechanism class contain all members that are common between the various classes that derive from Mechanism, and override any methods that may differ between the two but make sense to have in both. This also makes a decent case for Mechanism to be an Abstract Base Class.

A ridiculously over simplified example follows:

```
public class Mechanism {
    public string Vin {get;set;}
}

public class Auto : Mechanism {
    public int NumberOfDoors {get;set;

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", Vin, NumberOfDoors);
    }
}

public class Motorcycle : Mechanism {
    public string TypeOfMotorcycle {get;set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", Vin, TypeOfMotorcycle );
    }
}

foreach (Mechanism m in mechanisms) {
    Console.Print(m.ToString());
}
```